# How To get Browser Locale in build.gradle?

Tags: java, build.gradle

Can anyone suggest how to get browser locale in build.gradle.
I'm new to gradle, we are using Accept-Headers for fetching locale in JAVA Servlet class.

Is there any option to call that locale from java or get browser locale in build.gradle file?

```
task includeHelpContent(type: Copy) {
def en="en_properties.zip"
def ja="ja_properties.zip"
def locale = "en" || "ja"
def helpZipFile = file(locale)
println filename
println helpZipFile
```

In the above sample code, variable locale should be the current locale fetched from the browser locale dynamically.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Gradle is a build tool. It's used to build your application. There is no browser involved when you build your application.

Comment: is thr any option to pass loacle from java class to gradle

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What are you using gradle for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: we need to load the zip file based on browser locale dynamically

Comment: **dynamically** means **at runtime**. gradle is a build tool. It's not used at runtime. If, at runtime, you have users using 10 different locales that must load 10 corresponding zip files, then it means that your application must have those 10 zip files ready to be served. If those 10 zip files are static files, it thus means your gradle build must create these 10 zip files.

Comment: ok i will try !! thank you